# How do I fix innocuous error messages from lp regarding p11-kit?

Tags: printing, gnome-keyring

Any time I run `lpr` or `lpq`, I get this error message:

```
p11-kit: invalid config filename, will be ignored in the future: /etc/pkcs11/modules/gnome-keyring-module.dpkg-remove
```

The commands still work fine, but they always emit error. How can I stop generation of the error message?

The contents of the file:

```
# The file is installed/loaded from the default module p11-kit directory
module: gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so

# And where to store and lookup trust objects
x-trust-store: pkcs11:library-manufacturer=GNOME%20Keyring;serial=1:XDG:DEFAULT
x-trust-lookup: pkcs11:library-manufacturer=GNOME%20Keyring
```

Deleting the file removes the error message.